# Objective-C: How to list files from documents directory into a UITableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Below I have some code that lists files from my documents directory into a `UITableView`. However, the code is not correctly working and once I test on my device even though there is files in the documents directory, nothing is listed all displayed just displaying some blank cells. Here is the code I am currently using:

```
NSArray *filePathsArray;

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [filePathsArray count];   
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MainCell"];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"MainCell"];
        }
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        filePathsArray = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory  error:nil];
        cell.textLabel.text = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[filePathsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        return cell;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code, you are filling the array in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, and obviously

-`(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section`

is called before `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. So you need to initialize the contents of the array before reloading table view. Either put the following lines in ViewDidLoad or viewWillAppear Methods:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
filePathsArray = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory  error:nil];
```

And you should do handling like:

> ```
> -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
> {
>    if(!isDataLoading)  // if data loading has been completed, return the number of rows ELSE return 1
>    {
>
>        if ([filePathsArray count] > 0) 
>           return [filePathsArray count];
>        else 
>           return 1;
>     }
>
>   return 1;
> }
> ```

Note that I am returning a 1 when there are no files or when the data is loading, you can display a message like "Loading data..." or "No records found" in that cell. Make sure to set the `userInteractionEnabled` to `NO` for that cell else it may cause inconsistencies if the logic is not implemented properly.

Comment: Why should `numberOfRowsInSection:` return `1` when there are no files?

Comment: @maddy : In that row you can display a message like: "No records found" or any appropriate message so the user won't be confused.

Comment: @maddy : Make sure you set the userInteractionEnabled to No for that cell

Comment: Why? There is no need to disable interactions.

Comment: If you are going to post an answer that shows 1 row when there is no data, you need to also explain why, and not just in a comment later on. It's confusing as-is.

Comment: @maddy: I have updated the answer. Hope this will make sense now. Thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 2):

When `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` is called filePathsArray is nil, so 0 is returned from this method. Your code basically says "there are no rows in my tableView".
And the tableView does not ask for a cell if your tableView does not have any rows. So your method that fills the array is never called.

Move the following 3 lines of code into `- (void)viewDidLoad` or `- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated`

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
filePathsArray = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory  error:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(NSArray *)listFileAtPath:(NSString *)path
{    
    int count;

    NSArray *directoryContent = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:path error:NULL];

    for (count = 0; count < (int)[directoryContent count]; count++)
    {
        NSLog(@"File %d: %@", (count + 1), [directoryContent objectAtIndex:count]);
    }
    return directoryContent;
}

-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    paths = [self listFileAtPath:documentsDirectory];
}
```