# "*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'"

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, nsdocumentdirectory

I know this is a common question on Stack Overflow, but unfortunately none have been able to lead me to my solution.

I'm trying to list the files in my documents directory in a `UITableView`. (I also have another tableview displaying devices I'm connected to)

I know I'm getting this error because its saying that my array has 0 objects, and I'm trying to access the object at index 1.

But I have a file in my documents directory.
If I have 2 files, when I delete 1, I get this error. When the app is relaunched, it shows the `UITableView` correctly with the file deleted.

I got my code from here:
***[Objective-C: How to list files from documents directory into a UITableView?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17392769/3544744)***

this is my content:

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    if (tableView == _tblConnectedDevices){
    return [_arrConnectedDevices count];
    }
    if ([filePathsArray count] > 0){
        return [filePathsArray count];
    }
    else 
    return 1;
}


-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if (tableView == _tblConnectedDevices){
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellIdentifier"];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"CellIdentifier"];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [_arrConnectedDevices objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
    } else {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        filePathsArray = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory  error:nil];
        NSString *last = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[filePathsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        NSString *last2 = [[last lastPathComponent] stringByDeletingPathExtension];
        cell.textLabel.text = last2;
        return cell;
    }
}
```

My delete void:

```
-(IBAction)deleteFile:(id)sender{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                         NSUserDomainMask,
                                                         YES);
    NSString *fullPath = [[paths lastObject] stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.txt", fileName]];
    NSError *error;
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:fullPath error:&error];
    [_cellView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: You have some really strange logic in this code.
        filePathsArray = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory  error:nil]; in cellForRow.
And return [filePathsArray count]; in your number of rows. Are you sure that you understand what do you want to obtain?

Comment: Reload your filePathArray in deleteFile:
Also set breakpoint and look how many files you have in array.

Comment: I'm fairly new @PavelGatilov, I'm using code I've found online, and its working nicely displaying the files I want to see, the only thing I'm struggling with is after removing something from the documents directory, that the tableview reload correctly with the file removed.

Comment: So the code is _not_ working nicely.

Comment: @PavelGatilov thanks for your answer, if you post it ill mark it as correct answer, it worked. I added an if in my cellforRow checking if my array as empty also to check if the folder is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reload your filePathArray in deleteFile: Also set breakpoint and look how many files you have in array

Comment: Thank you,  I added an if in my cellforRow checking if my array as empty also to check if the folder is empty to put a blank cell text and its working.

Answer (score 0):

You should refactor your code. However:

I assume that you get the error in this line:

```
NSString *last = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[filePathsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

What's going wrong:

A. You have an array with the paths in-memory. When the table view asks you for the number of items, you return the count of that array.

B. When the table view asks for an item in a row, you read the directory. (Well, that's not that fast the method should be.)

```
filePathsArray = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory  error:nil];
```

Then you look for the file with the index of indexPath.row:

```
NSString *last = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[filePathsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

This "works" (it is akin of working) as long as you have at least as many files in the directory as in your array.

When you remove the file from the directory, it is still an item in the array. So you say to the table view that there are as many rows as items in the array. When the table view tries to get it, you look to the disk and find less files (the deleted is missed). So the array you get from disk has one item less than the items in-memory.

To fix it: Update your in-memory array. Or make a decision: Work in-memory *or* work on disk.